# How to separate parallel edges and remove start in automata in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, automata

I want to draw an automata in TikZ, and I have the following code segment:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm, scale = 1, transform shape]

\node[initial,state] (B)                                    {$B$};
\node[state]         (AB) [below of=B]                       {$A,B$};
\node[state]         (ABD) [right of=AB]                    {$A,B,D$};
\node[state,accepting]         (BC) [right of=B]                       {$B,C$};
\node[state,accepting]         (ABCD) [right of=BC]                       {$A,B,C,D$};

\path[->] (B) edge [above]  node [align=center]  {$a$} (BC)
      (B) edge [left]      node [align=center]  {$b$} (AB)
      (AB) edge [left]      node [align=center] {$a$} (BC)
      (AB) edge [above]     node [align=center] {$b$} (ABD)
      (BC) edge [loop above] node [align=center] {$a$} (BC)
      (BC) edge [above]      node [align=center] {$b$} (ABCD)
      (ABD) edge [right]     node [align=center] {$a$} (BC)
      (ABD) edge [loop below] node [align=center] {$b$} (ABD)
      (ABCD) edge [below]       node [align=center] {$a$} (BC)
      (ABCD) edge [loop above]  node [align=center] {$b$} (ABCD);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I have two problems with the output of this one, first of all at the initial state it has the arrow and additionally it writes `start`, how can I remove that `start` text? Secondly, As can be seen I have parallel edges, like:

```
 (BC) edge [above]      node [align=center] {$b$} (ABCD)
 (ABCD) edge [below]       node [align=center] {$a$} (BC)
```

But when they are drawn it looks like one thick line, how can I give some space between them so that it is clear that I have parallel connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the default text for the start node, `start`, add the option `initial text=`. You can bend edges a bit so that they become visible as separate lines; e.g., add `bend left=10`.

You don't have to add `align=center`, since this is the default. You also don't have to say on which side of the edge to put the label. If you don't like the default, just add the `swap`-option to the node, as e.g. in `(B) edge node[swap] {$a$} (BC)`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
   [>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm,
    scale = 1, transform shape]

\node[initial,state,initial text=] (B)                 {$B$};
\node[state]                       (AB)   [below of=B] {$A,B$};
\node[state]                       (ABD)  [right of=AB]{$A,B,D$};
\node[state,accepting]             (BC)   [right of=B] {$B,C$};
\node[state,accepting]             (ABCD) [right of=BC]{$A,B,C,D$};

\path[->]
  (B)    edge                node {$a$} (BC)
  (B)    edge                node {$b$} (AB)
  (AB)   edge                node {$a$} (BC)
  (AB)   edge                node {$b$} (ABD)
  (BC)   edge [loop above]   node {$a$} (BC)
  (BC)   edge [bend left=10] node {$b$} (ABCD)
  (ABD)  edge                node {$a$} (BC)
  (ABD)  edge [loop below]   node {$b$} (ABD)
  (ABCD) edge [bend left=10] node {$a$} (BC)
  (ABCD) edge [loop above]   node {$b$} (ABCD)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]